# Angular 4 dynamic headers based on user type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to implement a dynamic header component which changes based on user role.

Here is my header component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    currentUser:any;
  constructor(

  ) {
     this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')); 

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

This is my header template

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="menu_item" *ngIf="!currentUser"><a [routerLink]="['/login']"> Login </a></li>
    <li class="menu_item" *ngIf="currentUser"><a [routerLink]="['/signin']">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

But the problem is

- after logged in, that header text is not changing ( not changing
  login -> logout )
- after logout, that header text is not changing ( not changing
  logout -> login )
- But it change the header text if I refresh the page. But not changing automatically with the route change

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: What does it look like the user object

Comment: You set this.currentUser with the value from localStorage just once. Probably when user logs in/out, you change the value in the storage but the component does not 'read' this value again. You can use an EventEmitter for this or a shared service.

Comment: Can explain me how to implement it using a shared service

Comment: current user object is like this {  "token": "sample token", "role": 0}

Comment: Check Martin Adamek's answer, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let the HeaderComponent know that the authentication status has changed. You could use an observable for this:

1. introduce `isAuthenticated$` observable inside `AuthService`
2. inject that service in HeaderComponent, and use the `isAuthenticated$` inside the template, with async pipe
3. when logging in/out, call `next()` on that observable to trigger changes

Something like this should do the job:

```
class AuthService {

    isAuthenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor() {
        const authenticated = !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')); 
        this.isAuthenticated$.next(authenticated);
    }

    login() {
        this.isAuthenticated$.next(true);
    }

    logout() {
        this.isAuthenticated$.next(false);
    }

}
```

Header component controller:

```
class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentUser: any;
  public isAuthenticated$ = this.auth.isAuthenticated$;

  private (private auth: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated$.subscribe(authenticated => {
      if (authenticated) {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')); 
      } else {
        this.currentUser = null;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Your template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="menu_item" *ngIf="!(isAuthenticated$ | async)"><a [routerLink]="['/login']"> Login </a></li>
      <li class="menu_item" *ngIf="(isAuthenticated$ | async) && currentUser.someField === 'someValue'"><a [routerLink]="['/signin']">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This approach is not applicable to my problem. Because I really need to check the condition using the 'currentuser' object. Because there are more than one user types and I need to change the header dynamically based on those  user types.

Comment: Then you can subscribe to `isAuthenticated$` and update the `currentUser` when its changed. Will update my answer.

Comment: Or you can use `currentUser$` observable in the same way.

Comment: can you explain this code segment *ngIf="!(isAuthenticated$ | async)"

Comment: That is async pipe in the action. It is used for working with observables inside templates. It will subscribe to the observable and return its value every time it changes (the brackets are there because the negation). More about it: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Still there is an issue. Now when logged in header is changing ( login -> logout). but if i refresh the page, It again changes (Logout -> login)

Comment: Thats because default value of `isAuthenticated$` is `false`. Just set that value in `AuthService` contructor based on the `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ng-template

```
  `  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <ng-template #anonymousUser>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
                  </li>
                </ng-template>

                <li ngbDropdown *ngIf="appUser ;else anonymousUser " class="nav-item dropdown ">
                  <a ngbDropdownToggle class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    {{appUser.name}}</a>
                  <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/my/orders">My Orders</a>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="appUser.isAdmin">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/orders">Manage Order</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/admin/products">Manage Products</a>
                    </ng-container>

                    <a class="dropdown-item" (click)=logOut()>Log Out</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>`
```